# React props "undefined" in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm following a YouTube tutorial about a ReactJS project (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IATOicvih5A&t=3872s). It's basically a TikTok clone with an Astra Database using Netlify CLI to run a local development server. So far so great!

However, in the tutorial I'm stuck at around 1:04:00 when she's passing the user data prop to the Card component. Passing the props to the Card component works, when I console.log it shows up in my browser console but whenever I try to use the prop (ie: `<p className="username">{user.name}</p>` I get an "undefined" error. I just don't get why it works on her project and not on mine, I even tried copy pasting her code to my project but it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated please

For instance, the data looks like that:

```
const data = [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "Mo Farooq",
                username: "mofarooq32",
                avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/9KYq7VG.png",
                is_followed: true,
                video: "https://i.imgur.com/FTBP02Y.mp4",
                caption: "These ducks are MEGA cute",
                likes: 10,
                comments: 2,
                timestamp: "2019-03-10T09:08:31.020Z",
                button_visible: true,
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                name: "Tim Salowski",
                username: "timmytam",
                avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/rWYtZa6.png",
                is_followed: false,
                video: "https://i.imgur.com/1A7AKoF.mp4",
                caption: "When your fries give you attitude #getInMyBelly",
                likes: 12,
                comments: 2,
                timestamp: "2020-03-10T09:08:31.020Z",
                button_visible: true,
              },
    ]
```

I pass the props to the Card component by doing:

```
{descendingUsers.map((descendingUser, index) => (
                        <Card 
                            key={index}
                            user={descendingUser}
                        />
                    ))}
```

And in my Card component, I try to get the props to work properly by doing:

```
const Card = ({user}) => {
    console.log(user)

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="break" />
                <div className="section">
                    <div className="user-info">
                        <img className="user-profile" alt="avatar" src={user.avatar} width={'100%'} />
                        <div>
                            <div className="section">
                                <h3 className="bold">{user.username}</h3>
                                <p className="username">{user.name}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{user.caption}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Card;
```

and when I console.log(user) in my Card component, I get this in my browser console:

```
[Log] Object (main.chunk.js, line 165)

0: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/jONHmE5.png", button_visible: true, caption: "Art is for everyone", comments: 20, id: 0, …}

1: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/rWYtZa6.png", button_visible: true, caption: "When your fries give you attitude #getInMyBelly", comments: 2, id: 1, …}

2: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/eX3hkoc.png", button_visible: true, caption: "Happiest of Birthdays my Angel", comments: 4, id: 2, …}

3: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/IigY4Hm.png", button_visible: true, caption: "The new normal", comments: 2, id: 3, …}

4: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/jONHmE5.png", button_visible: true, caption: "Art is for everyone", comments: 20, id: 4, …}

Prototype Object
```

Thanks a lot in advance, I've been stuck all day

Comment: you can try React Developer Tools and check the status of the state variables in your components. At the beginning the state might be empty and at a later stage, its filled.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann I did it and the state is filled, now I don't know how to display the props properly

Answer (score 0):

Probably its due to the api call happening asynchronously. Try adding a condition before return like if(user username) then return the html content.

Answer (score 0):

you may have problem with asynchronous behavior of fetch
try these as they make sure your objects are not undefined :

```
{descendingUsers && descendingUsers.map((descendingUser, index) => (
                        <Card 
                            key={index}
                            user={descendingUser}
                        />
                    ))}
```

and

```
const Card = ({user}) => {
    console.log(user)

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="break" />
                <div className="section">
                    <div className="user-info">
                        <img className="user-profile" alt="avatar" src={user && user.avatar} width={'100%'} />
                        <div>
                            <div className="section">
                                <h3 className="bold">{user && user.username}</h3>
                                <p className="username">{user &&‌ user.name}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{user && user.caption}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried it but it still doesn't work. I don't think it's an asynchronous problem as I believe I just don't know how to use the props properly in my Card component. When I console.log(user) I get the list of the data, and when I console.log(user[0]) I get the first index of my Array. So, should I loop my props in my Card component in order to display them properly with a for each or for or?

Comment: did you try to receive props as 'props' object itself?i mean not by destructuring it: const Card = (props) => .. . and then accessing objects via props.user.property

Comment: Alright so If I console.log(props.user) I get an object of multiple objects
```
[Log] Object (main.58c0c7c8b29168ffcab4.hot-update.js, line 28)

0: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/jONHmE5.png", button_visible: true, caption: "Art is for everyone", comments: 20, id: 0, …}

1: {avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/rWYtZa6.png", button_visible: true, caption: "When your fries give you attitude #getInMyBelly", comments: 2, id: 1, …}

Prototype Object
```
and if I try to console.log(props.user.avatar) I get undefined